# Changing values in dataframe based on cell and column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```py
df=pd.DataFrame( [0,1,2],columns=[‘3m3a’,’1z6n’,’11p66d’])
```

Now i would like to apply 2 * value * (last numbers of column name). Eg for the last 2 * 2* 66

`Df.apply(lambda x: 2*x)` for step 1

Step 2 is the hardest part

Can do new dataframe like `df2=df.stack().reset_index().apply(lambda x: x[re.search(‘[azAZ]+’,x).end():])` and then multiple the `2`.

What’s a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 0):

For DataFrame:

```
   3m3a  1z6n  11p66d
0     0     1       2
```

You can use `.colums.str.extract` and then `DataFrame.multiply`:

```
vals = df.columns.str.extract(r"(\d+)[a-z]*?$").T.astype(int)
df = df.multiply(2 * vals.values, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   3m3a  1z6n  11p66d
0     0    12     264
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, and having found almost the same answer, but using negative look-behind regex:

```py
newdf = df.multiply(
    2 * df.columns.str.extract(r'.*(?<!\d)(\d+)\D*').astype(int).values.ravel(),
    axis=1)

>>> newdf
   3m3a  1z6n  11p66d
0     0    12     264
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that both works
what if i would like to split the column in 2 parts, one up to and including the first letter, and the second the part after

```
df.columns.str.split(r"(\d+\D+)",n=1,expand=True)
```

work but give me a 3 part with first blank